# Проверка аргументов командной строки на наличие

Tags: c++, argv

Всем привет, помогите разобраться с проверкой.
Если ввести только флаг --calc, то в программу будут переданы не все параметры, а она будет пытаться прочитать все

Я хочу проверять поступают ли данные на вход
Как такое реализовать на плюсах?

Вот сама задача

Разработать программу которая получает данные из командной строки и реализует следуюший функционал:
a) без параметров кратко пишет назначение программы и подсказывает как получить помощь
b) -h (--help) - выдает подробную справку по программе
c) -t (--table) - выдает в табличном виде размеры всех простых типов языка C/C++
d) -x (--hex) число - выдает шестнадцатиричное значение заданного числа
e) -c (--calc) арифметическое выражение расчитывает простое арифметическое выражение вида число операция число
f) если ввод не соответствует командам, то выдать предупреждение и приглашение воспользоваться справкой для вывода

код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string cmdH = "-h";
    string cmdT = "-t";
    string cmdX = "-x";
    string cmdC = "-c";
    string  arg;

    if (argc == 1) {
        cout << "Лабораторная работа №1 \n";
        cout << "1.При вводе 'h' программа выдаст подробную справку с функционалом программы,если вдруг возникли какие-то проблемы.\n";
        cout << "2.При вводе 't' программа выдаст в табличном виде размеры всех простых типов языка C/C++.\n";
        cout << "3.При вводе 'x' программа выдаст шестнадцатиричное значение заданного числа. \n";
        cout << "4.При вводе 'c' программа выдаст 3 строки,где нужно ввести 2 числа и арифметическое действие. \n";
    }
    else {
        string cmd = argv[1];
        if (argc >= 2) arg = argv[1]; if ((arg == "--help" || arg == "-h") && argc == 2) {
            if (cmd == cmdH) {
                cout << "1.При вводе 't' программа выдаст в табличном виде размеры всех простых типов языка C/C++.\n";
                cout << "2.При вводе 'x' программа выдаст шестнадцатиричное значение заданного числа. \n";
                cout << "3.При вводе 'c' программа выдаст 3 строки,где нужно ввести первое число-арифметическое действие-второе число. \n";
            }
        }
        else if (arg == "--table" || arg == "-t") {
            cout << "bool:\t\t" << sizeof(bool) << " bytes" << endl;
            cout << "char:\t\t" << sizeof(char) << " bytes" << endl;
            cout << "wchar_t:\t" << sizeof(wchar_t) << " bytes" << endl;
            cout << "char16_t:\t" << sizeof(char16_t) << " bytes" << endl;
            cout << "char32_t:\t" << sizeof(char32_t) << " bytes" << endl;
            cout << "short:\t\t" << sizeof(short) << " bytes" << endl;
            cout << "int:\t\t" << sizeof(int) << " bytes" << endl;
            cout << "long:\t\t" << sizeof(long) << " bytes" << endl;
            cout << "long long:\t" << sizeof(long long) << " bytes" << endl;
            cout << "float:\t\t" << sizeof(float) << " bytes" << endl;
            cout << "double:\t\t" << sizeof(double) << " bytes" << endl;
            cout << "long double:\t" << sizeof(long double) << " bytes" << endl;
        }
        else if (arg == "--hex" || arg == "-x") {
            cout << " Результат: ";
            cout << hex << atoi(argv[2]) << dec << endl;
        }
        
        else if (arg == "--calc" || arg == "-c") {
        int a = atoi(argv[2]);
        int b = atoi(argv[4]);
        char oper = argv[3][0];
            if (oper == '+')
                cout << dec << "Результат сложения: " << a + b << endl;
            else if (oper == '-') 
                cout << dec << "Результат вычитания: " << a - b << endl;
            else if (oper == '*') 
                cout << dec << "Результат умножения: " << a * b << endl;
            else if (oper == '/') 
                cout << dec << "Результат деления: " << a / b << endl;
            else if ((oper != '/') && (oper != '*') && (oper != '+') && (oper != '-')) {
                cout << "Что-то пошло не так... Попробуйте снова. .\n";
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "ОШИБКА! Воспользуйтесь справкой,для этого введите h. \n";
        }

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А argc перестал работать?

Comment: надо просто добавить ещё один if после проверки "-calc" (да, я бы именно отдельный if делал бы) и проверить argc на нужное кол-во. Почему именно так? просто плохо выбрасывать всегда сразу в справку

Comment: Программа получает с командной строки не параметры, а строку целиком. Просто стартовый код, который выполняется перед вызовом функции main(), стандартно распарсивает эту строку на параметры и передаёт их функции main() в виде аргументов argc и argv[]. Но вы можете придумать любой синтаксис командной строки, получить её с помощью GetCommandLine() (если пишете под Windows) и распарсить по-своему.

Comment: Вот [тут](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html) хорошо все об аргументах командной строки написано

Answer (score 0):

Как самый простой вариант, замените это

```cpp
else if (arg == "--calc" || arg == "-c")
```

на это

```cpp
else if ((arg == "--calc" || arg == "-c") && (argc == 5))
```

то есть я предлагаю просто добавить проверку нужного кол-ва аргументов (количество переданных аргументов, включая название программы, кладётся в `argc`) в `if`. Для вызова программы с параметром `--calc` нужно, чтобы аргументов было 5:

1. Название программы (всегда передаётся первым).
2. Параметр `--calc`.
3. Первый операнд (число).
4. Оператор (+, -, /, *, и т.д.).
5. Второй операнд (число).

Следовательно, я добавил проверку на то, что `argc == 5`.

Это не затронет и не сделает лучше логику Вашей программы, но суть вопроса состоит не в этом. Теперь, как Вы и хотели, при вводе неверного количества аргументов будет выдана ошибка.